# Import into lazy loaded module in Angular5

Tags: angular5, lazy-loading

Trying to group some components into lazy loading modules and getting an issue with material imports:

```
error: Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatCheckbox -> InjectionToken mat-checkbox-click-action]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatCheckbox -> InjectionToken mat-checkbox-click-action]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken mat-checkbox-click-action!)
```

Same error appears for most of material components (e.g. mat-checkbox), but for example it works fine with mat-icon:

```
#working fine:
<mat-icon>phone</mat-icon>
<mat-slider min="1" max="5" step="0.5" value="1.5"></mat-slider>

#errors:
<mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>
<mat-radio-group>
   <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<mat-checkbox>Hello world</mat-checkbox>
```

I have following architecture of the app:

- app.module imports dashboard.module in non-lazy way
- dashboard.module imports test.module in lazy way
- test.module has a component with error described above

What type of problem is this? Am I missing some import?
Is it OK to have lazy loading in sub-modules as in this case?

EDIT:

#app.module.ts (app module simplified)

```
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';


const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard/test',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }),
        DashboardModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,

   ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent],
export class AppModule {
}
```

#module.ts (dashboard module simplified)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DashboardResolver } from './test/resolver';
import { DashboardComponent } from './test/component';

const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'test',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                loadChildren: './test/module#DashboardTestModule',
                data: {loginStatusShouldBe: true},
                resolve: {
                    test: DashboardResolver,
            },
        },
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes),
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        DashboardResolver,
    ],
export class DashboardModule {
}
```

#module.ts (test module simplified)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TestComponent } from './component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const testRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: TestComponent,
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(testRoutes),
    ],
    declarations: [
        TestComponent,
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule,
    ],
})
export class DashboardTestModule {
}
```

Comment: Could you attach your modules definitions?

Comment: @AlejandroCamba added simplified modules definitions, otherwise those are huge files but tried to pick core things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are missing provider in your module. Add `MAT_CHECKBOX_CLICK_ACTION` in to your app module:

```
providers: [
    ...,
    MAT_CHECKBOX_CLICK_ACTION
]
```

or `MatCheckboxModule` in to your app module:

```
imports: [
    ...,
    MatCheckboxModule
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea Dipen but it doesn't change anything. I added to my example code too.

Comment: @jokuja even after adding matcheckboxclickaction it's not working? May be we are missing something and having MVP would help.

Comment: When added MAT_CHECKBOX_CLICK_ACTION, error has changed into: 

error: Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatRipple -> InjectionToken mat-ripple-global-options]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatRipple -> InjectionToken mat-ripple-global-options]:

Comment: @jokija In that case your approach should be to add missing providers one after another untill error gets resolved. It looks like your app module is missing few imports and/or providers.

Comment: Yes this is an easy part now, made it work. Many thanks! But do you have an idea why material doesn't import this automatically?

Comment: I believe that because of lazy loading. Each module will be bundled with their own dependencies and that will mean some required modules are missing from your main module. In non lazy loaded mode, you gave everything available so if one module is loading it's dependencies, they will become available to app. May be you should check which module in your codebase is using providers and import it with app module.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to previous idea, resolved in a following way:

```
 import {MatCheckboxModule, MAT_CHECKBOX_CLICK_ACTION} from '@angular/material/checkbox';

...

 {provide: MAT_CHECKBOX_CLICK_ACTION, useValue: 'check'},
```